# Why does this XPath expression not return the correct value in xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, xpath, kml, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to extract the contents of the 'coordinates' node in this KML file using xmlstarlet.

The KML file validates fine using xmlstarlet itself.

I've whittled it down to a small test file containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark>
    <name>eurovelo-5 690</name>
    <Snippet></Snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#style390</styleUrl>
    <LineString>
      <tessellate>1</tessellate>
      <coordinates>
        10.146948,44.790592,97.500000
        10.146958,44.790562,97.599998
        10.147018,44.790497,97.699997
        10.147083,44.790466,97.699997
      </coordinates>
    </LineString>
  </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Running this query fails though:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//coordinates/text()" test.kml
```

This appears to parse correctly using the online path tool - http://www.qutoric.com/xslt/analyser/xpathtool.html

Am I missing something here?

Comment: PathEnq, the online xpath tool you reference is an XPath 2.0 tool - it therefore recognises the default namespace in the XML - an XPath 1.0 tool such as xmlstarlet does not recognize the default namespace it therefore requires you to define the namespace with a prefix - as stated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define and use a namespace prefix for `http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2 test.kml` - something like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//kml:coordinates/text()" -N kml=http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2 test.kml
```

XPaths do not have a default namespace - if a name in a XPath does not specify a namespace prefix it is assumed to be in the null namespace; hence it is necessary to always specify a namespace prefix when trying to match nodes whose names are in a namespace different from the null one (as in this case).